# Redirecting URL or hiding URL information

Tags: php, spring, servlets, struts2

Its about redirecting the url. I am redirecting below url "A" to
"B".  In browser i get "B". My question is i don want to display "B" on my browser, but instead should display "A". I don't want customer to know about "B" url.How can i achieve this.

Comment: please provide some detail: are you using Apache and PHP?

Comment: @AkamOmer tag spring servlets ...

Comment: does mapping url B to Servlet A  work?

Comment: I am sorry, I really don't know anything about it :(

Comment: Then you probably don't want to redirect but handle the result internally and render content. An action may have multiple views. Please be more specific with your requirements and what you have tried.

Comment: I just noticed you have this tagged struts2 AND php... voting to close because as the question stands it can't be answered.

Comment: This application is basically PHP based application. Since i don know PHP, i thought if i can get some idea from java side.

Comment: You can use AJAX for it no matter what language php or java you use.

Comment: So with AJAX I can to hide the Parent url from the customer so that he thinks the application is on his server rather than on someone elses. Can you please give me example

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is an instruction from the server to the client telling the client to request a new URL. If you don't want the client to know about this URL, then a redirect is the wrong thing for you. If you describe what you're trying to achieve more fully, then someone might be able to suggest a better alternative. For now, I'd suggest you look at either [Filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) or ["Invoking Other Web Resources"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagi.html), as the tutorial puts it. Specifically, it's talking about [including](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) and [forwarding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) via a request dispatcher.

Comment: Actually i don want client to know about URL B as a security point of view. It is like information hiding.

Comment: What would be the other alternative if redirection is wrong in my case.

Comment: I already mentioned some general alternatives in my answer. If that's not enough, then you need to add details to your question so we know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have one CRM application at client side. Once that application is submitted it is redirected to parent application which i own. I don want customer where actually it is redirected.